# Get php version files to Wamp

Tags: php

I have WampServer 1.6.1.33 and I want to add a `php 5.3` version on it.
How I can do it. And where can I find the files?

I got 5.5 and 5.6 and 7 files but did not find 5.3.

Comment: Isn't WampServer 1.6.1.33 super old?  Why not update to the latest version?  From there, you can install PHP 5.3 from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Php/

Comment: When will MS-Windows _finally_ get a usable software management system like all other operating systems out there? This issue has been solved in a secure and convenient manner about 20-30 years ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the php version binaries you want from [php.net](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/), then extract the files in `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3/`, add the `wampserver.conf` file to this folder (you can copy it from the others php versions folders), then rename `php.ini-development` file to `phpForApache.ini` and restart the server

A similar question was answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/569472).

Comment: Where can I find `wampserver.conf`?

Comment: @mosessaleh you can find `wampserver.conf ` file in the others php versions foolder (ex: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`) just copy it from there.

Comment: But the icon changed to yellow.

Answer (score 0):

They are on the [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) site under the archives. Also a [GUIDE ON INSTALLING IT](http://markushedlund.com/dev/install-php-5.3.3-on-wamp) is here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of wampserver.

Use this link:

https://kostasbariotis.com/multiple-php-versions-on-wampserver/